# Excel VBA - open activex control DTPicker1 within a sub

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker, activex

i have a date picker activex control in my worksheet. after a subroutine i would like the datepicker to open instead of having to rely on the user to navigate and click the box to open it

when i click 'view code' on the control i see it is names like this

```
Private Sub DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)

End Sub
```

what would be the appropriate way to call/simulate this keydown event in another sub

example:

```
Sub ProcessResults
    'do existing code
     DTPicker1.KeyDown 'doesn't work - 424 object required
     DTPicker1.Open 'doesn't work - 424 object required
     DTPicker1.Activate 'doesn't work - 424 object required
     DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown 'doesn't work - sub or function not defined
End Sub
```

DTPicker1 itself works fine within the worksheet - like i said i just want to save a few clicks and have it open automatically at the end of a different sub

Answer (score 0):

Focus DTPicker and do
SendKeys ("{F4}")

Comment: Add some explanation, please